# Selected Index and the Sorted Method not synergising

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to sort a list in my Listbox by just using listBox.Sorted = true;

The problem with this is that if I were to select the fourth thing on the list, it would select the fourth inserted thing, not the fourth thing after being sorted.

So im thinking listBox.Sorted is only sorting what's actually being displayed, but not the raw lists behind it.

```
        private void Form1_Load()
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xDoc.Load(path + "\\contactz\\testing.xml");
            foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("People/Person"))
            {
                Person p = new Person();
                p.surname = xNode.SelectSingleNode("surname").InnerText;
                p.first_name = xNode.SelectSingleNode("first_name").InnerText;
                p.street_address = xNode.SelectSingleNode("street_address").InnerText;
                p.postcode = xNode.SelectSingleNode("postcode").InnerText;
                p.suburb = xNode.SelectSingleNode("suburb").InnerText;
                p.email = xNode.SelectSingleNode("email").InnerText;
                p.phone = xNode.SelectSingleNode("phone").InnerText;
                p.mobile_phone = xNode.SelectSingleNode("mobile_phone").InnerText;
                people.Add(p);
                listBox.Items.Add(p.surname + ", " + p.first_name);
                listBox.Sorted = true;

        }


        private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (listBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            surnameTxt.Text = people[listBox.SelectedIndex].surname;
            firstnameTxt.Text = people[listBox.SelectedIndex].first_name;
            addressTxt.Text = people[listBox.SelectedIndex].street_address;
            suburbTxt.Text = people[listBox.SelectedIndex].suburb;
            postcodeTxt.Text = people[listBox.SelectedIndex].postcode;
            emailTxt.Text = people[listBox.SelectedIndex].email;
            phoneTxt.Text = people[listBox.SelectedIndex].phone;
            mobileTxt.Text = people[listBox.SelectedIndex].mobile_phone;

        }
    }
```

Deleted a lot of unnecessary code so it may look a bit funky.

I tried setting the listBox.topIndex to 0 at a few points but that doesnt seem to do anything.

Thanks

Comment: try by keeping  listBox.Sorted = true; after foreach loop ends means after addition of all items in the list completes

Comment: @V2Solutions-MSTeam Tried this but it still seems to be having the same problem. Perhaps I should use a different Method to sort the List?

Answer (score 1):

From your code you are sorting `listBox.Items` not the `people` and you didn't use `people` as the `Datasource` of the `listBox` :

```
 //....
 people.Add(p);
 listBox.Items.Add(p.surname + ", " + p.first_name);
 listBox.Sorted = true;
 //....
```

And that is why you can't get the correct item from `people` using `SelectedIndex` of `listbox`. Like what you have done, as they are not linked in anyway:

```
 surnameTxt.Text = people[listBox.SelectedIndex].surname;
```

Instead, you could Set `listBox.DataSource=people` and just sort the `people`.

Please note, you should not using [`ListBox.Sorted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx) property to sort the list, when it's bound to a `DataSource`:

> A ListBox with its Sorted set to true should not be bound to data using the DataSource property. To display sorted data in a bound ListBox, you should bind to a data source that supports sorting and have the data source provide the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `listBox.Sorted = true;`

I went with sorting the actual list by using;

```
people.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.surname, y.surname));
```

Works perfectly now.